# How to select file and send it to vlc player

Tags: unix

I want to start a song using command terminal.

In my directory when i do ls it prints

```
ls
AlbumArtSmall.jpg
Folder.jpg
[SongsPK.info] Table No 21 - 02 - Man Mera.mp3
[Songs.PK] Table No 21 - 01 - O Sajna.mp3
[Songs.PK] Table No 21 - 02 - Man Mera.mp3
```

and i want to play the third song,
so i wrote this command

```
ls |sed -n "3p"|vlc
```

but it is not playing the song,vlc player just opens up,but doesn't play.
How to solve this?

after trying the answer below like

```
ls|sed -n "3p"|xargs -0 vlc
```

gave me another error

```
VLC media player 2.2.0 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-0-g1349ef2)
[00000000018eb118] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007fea5c000f28] filesystem access error: cannot open file /media/gautam/S.T.U.F.F/songs/table no.21/[SongsPK.info] Table No 21 - 02 - Man Mera.mp3
 (No such file or directory)
[00007fea600009b8] core input error: open of `file:///media/gautam/S.T.U.F.F/songs/table%20no.21/%5BSongsPK.info%5D%20Table%20No%2021%20-%2002%20-%20Man%20Mera.mp3%0A' failed
```

can someone explain me why this is happening??

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ls|sed -n "3p"|xargs -0 vlc
> ```
>
> gave me another error
>
> ```
> open of `…%5BSongsPK.info%5D%20Table%20No%2021%20-%2002%20-%20Man%20Mera.mp3%0A' failed
> ```
>
> can someone explain me why this is happening??

This is happening because the option `-0` of `xargs` causes the newline character after the filename to not be removed (as we see in the `%0A` above).
You can correct and at the same time simplify the command to:

```
vlc "`ls|sed -n 3p`"
```

Answer (score 1):

vlc expects filenames to be passed as command line arguments, which is what you're NOT doing. You're passing the filenames into vlc's stdin, where it isn't looking/expecting them.

Try

```
... | xargs vlc
```

instead. xargs takes things from stdin (the pipe) and turns them into command line arguments.

Comment: [00007f5e500023d8] core stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
[00007f5e50002508] filesystem access error: cannot open file /media/gautam/S.T.U.F.F/songs/table no.21/Man (No such file or directory)
[00007f5e7000c018] core input error: open of `file:///media/gautam/S.T.U.F.F/songs/table%20no.21/Man' failed
[00007f5e50002a68] filesystem access error: cannot open file /media/gautam/S.T.U.F.F/songs/table no.21/Mera.mp3 (No such file or directory)
[00007f5e7000cbe8] core input error: open of `file:///media/gautam/S.T.U.F.F/songs/table%20no.21/Mera.mp3' failed

Answer (score 1):

The other answer explains the issue but I'd just like to propose a cleaner solution (in my opinion):

```
find -iname "*mp3" | shuf | xargs --delimiter '\n' /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC
```

The key is the `--delimiter '\n'` option to xargs.

Side-note - I didn't realize you could do this. Glad this was posted.